# htaccess slash loading resources

Tags: php, .htaccess, resources, rewriting

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Some extra conditions
    # skip these paths for redirection
    RewriteRule ^img/(.*) public/assets/img/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*) public/assets/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*) public/assets/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) public/assets/plugins/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This rewriting is working except that when I load a URL like this `localhost/login/` (trailing slash) it is not loading the resources. When I use `localhost/login` it is and loads all the images and CSS files. Can somebody please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: These type of questions are probably a better fit for the [Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using relative paths in your HTML. With an additional slash on the end of the URL you are effectively inside another subfolder as far as client-side URLs are concerned.

To get around this, use root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs in your client-side code. For example:

```
/img/picture.jpg
```

Or if you can't modify your URLs, include a `base` element in the `head` section that instructs the browser what relative URLs are relative to. For example, to have them relative to the document root:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or, prevent trailing slashes from returning a valid document by redirecting to the non-slash URL in .htaccess, or handling this in `index.php`.